# Validation of viewstate MAC failed. - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have an C# ASP.net website hosted with www.blacknight.com.

Sometimes when I login to my website I get the following error:

[image]

This happens in about 1 in ever 10 login attempts.  I have contacted them and they assured me that its not hosted on a Web Farm or cluster and to check my ViewState.

Does anyone know what could be wrong here? I cant reproduce it everytime so its hard to track down.

Comment: That can happens when using Ajax. If not please add a machinekey in your web.config file

Answer (score 2):

Please see the KB article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218 for a resolution to this issue.  In particular, you should set an explicit <machineKey> element in Web.config.

Appendix A of that article tells you how to generate a <machineKey> element.

**Never** set EnableViewStateMac=false.  And you should **never** use a key that you got from a third-party generator.  Only use one that you generated yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that IIS is recycling your application between the original page load, and the login attempt? If you don't specify a `<machinekey />` in the web.config, a new machine key will be generated on application start up. And then, when you attempt to validate the viewstate that was generated on the old machine key during post back, this exception would be thrown.

Comment: Hmm I don't know to be honest.  So should I just add a <machinekey> and see if that works??

Comment: @HarryBoy Yeah, I would add a machine key and see if resolves the issue.

Comment: Ok I generated one from http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/GenerateMachineKey/GenerateMachineKey.aspx and have added it under <system.web>.  Re publish and see how it goes.  If this is not correct please let me know.  THanks

Comment: you should never use a key that you got from a third-party generator. Only use one that you generated yourself.